# Creating / displaying content in WordPress from external website through an AJAX API

Tags: ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am looking at a solution to display data from an external website in wordpress. The method I have been given to access the data is through an AJAX API. I have seen some articles about adding content via ajax into a plugin, but what I would like is for the data to create individual posts.Is this possible? if so what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: yes it is possible. you can use wp_insert_post function or use WP REST API V2

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's given me something to start on. So I guess I would add this to some code in functions.php?

Comment: it depends on how you want a content to be posted into your website. usually i create a custom php script and run it from cron jobs in my cpanel account..